# Making toolbars/Menus in tkinter with python3 Mountain Lion

Tags: python, tkinter

After tinkering around with tkinter I can't seem to make my window look
quite how I want it to look. But overall, I'm not sure what the File Edit View
layout is referred to. Is this is a toolbar or a menu?

So far my gui looks much less native osx than I would like. Should I just ditch
tkinter all together?

Does anyone have a code snipped that gives the general osx layout? That would be a big help.
Maybe I'm just not grasping the gui programming aspect conceptually.

thanks

I want to add menus to the following code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def undef(*args):
    pass
def undef2(*args):
    pass

root = Tk()


root.title("KDM Checker Beta ")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="5 5 5 5")
mainframe.grid(column=12, row=12, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)






countryvar = StringVar()
country = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable=countryvar)
country['values'] = ('dolby', 'sony', 'doremi')
country.grid(column=1, row = 1)


DATE = StringVar()
VENUE = StringVar()
UUID = StringVar()
SERVER_SERIAL = StringVar()

DATE_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=8, textvariable=DATE)
DATE_entry.grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=(W, E))

VENUE_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=8, textvariable=VENUE)
VENUE_entry.grid(column=3, row=8, sticky=(W, E))

UUID_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=8, textvariable=UUID)
UUID_entry.grid(column=3, row=16, sticky=(W, E))



state = StringVar()
mount = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='dolby', variable=state, value='dolby')






ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=DATE).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=VENUE).grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=UUID).grid(column=1, row=16, sticky=(W, E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="KDM Window").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Venue").grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="UUID").grid(column=1, row=16, sticky=E)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=3, pady=9)

DATE_entry.focus()

root.bind('<Return>', undef)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "The File Edit View layout" makes no sense. Did you read that phrase somewhere? Typically, GUI programs will have a menubar with menus labelled "File", "Edit", and "View". Is that what you are referring to? Have you tried to create these menus and failed? If so, what did you try? As it stands now, your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I mean the top of an application in osx that usually contains the Name of the app -> then File which is next to View, etc.

Comment: So it's really a matter of menus and the labels? That's what I was getting at.

Comment: @user124541: yes, you need to create a menu that acts as the menubar. I've added an answer showing an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a menubar you need to create an instance of the `Menu` class, then use it as the value of the `menubar` attribute of your main application. From there you can create other menus and attach them to the menubar with `add_cascade`.

For example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._create_menubar()
        self.text = tk.Text()
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def _create_menubar(self):
        # create a menu for the menubar and associate it
        # with the window
        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        self.configure(menu=self.menubar)

        # create a File menu and add it to the menubar
        file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.on_quit)

        # create a Edit menu and add it to the menubar
        edit_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut", underline=2, command=self.on_cut)
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=0, command=self.on_copy)
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Paste", underline=0, command=self.on_paste)

        # create a View menu and add it to the menubar
        view_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=view_menu)
        view_menu.add_cascade(label="Whatever", command=self.on_whatever)

    def log(self, s):
        self.text.insert("end", s + "\n")
        self.text.see("end")

    # not good programming style, but I'm trying to keep 
    # the example short
    def on_cut(self): self.log("cut...")
    def on_copy(self): self.log("copy...")
    def on_paste(self): self.log("paste...")
    def on_quit(self): sys.exit(0)
    def on_whatever(self): self.log("whatever...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```